# Destructuring Nested Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

If I have an array of objects that also has nested arrays, how do I get/destructure the sub array? For instance, what if I want to create a new array with only address object?

```
const people = [
  {
    name: "Jane",
    address: {
      street: "123 Main St",
      city: "Broadway"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    address: {
      street: "123 Other St",
      city: "Manhattan"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: That's not really destructuring, what your after is map.. -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: `people.map(p => p.address)`

Comment: Just use `Array.prototype.map` to do it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```js
const people = [
  {
    name: "Jane",
    address: {
      street: "123 Main St",
      city: "Broadway"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    address: {
      street: "123 Other St",
      city: "Manhattan"
    }
  }
]

const address=people.map((item)=>item.address)
console.log(address);
```